# Uploading and viewing pdf in django

Tags: python, django

I am making a Webapp using django. In the app, users can login and upload one pdf file. Then others users can visit their profile and view/download the uploaded pdf file. I know how to upload the pdf. But how do I make it viewable and downloadable from the site??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view you could use the below code.

```
with open('file.pdf', 'r') as pdf_document:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf_document.read(),contenttype ='application/pdf')
```

To add download functionality, you can set 'Content-Disposition' property as shown below.

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=pdf_file.pdf'
```

Comment: ```with open('file.pdf', 'r')``` I should put the url to the pdf file in database. Right?

Answer (score 0):

do this in template

```
<a href={{model_field_name.url}} class= btn btn-primary>download pdf</a>
```

this will create a button link to the pdf file and render it in pdf extension where you can view or download it.

Comment: thank you! It works. I have one more question... This pdf and a photo(through imagefield) are included in the user creation form. I have a user change form as well. I can change all other textfields but cannot change the uploaded pdf or image file. Here's a link to that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134522/changing-image-in-django-user-change-form/62134659#62134659